# Buying temp role command in economy bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making an economy bot by json file. I need help with command, which can delete some money from user's balance in json file and add him role for a week or month.

If you are interested in, there are my helper functions:

```
async def open_account(user):
    
    users = await get_bank_data()


    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    return True


async def update_bank(user, change = 0, mode = "wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    bal = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]

    return bal
```

I have no idea how to realise it, if you have, please write in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bot.command()
async def command_name(ctx):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    user = ctx.author

    bal = await update_bank(user)

    if 2500>bal:
        await ctx.send("You don't have that much money")
        return

    await update_bank(user, -2500, "wallet")

    await user.add_roles(sub_role)

    emb = discord.Embed(description = "You bought role for a week!", color = 0x2ecc71)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)

    await asyncio.sleep(604800)
    await user.remove_roles(sub_role)
```